# Process tesseract output: remove line breaks, concatenate individual pages

Tags: command-line, pdf, text-processing, ocr

I have a pdf that I cannot directly process into .txt to go through piper TTS because the output from the .pdf is missing letters and otherwise generally unintelligible (https://pastebin.com/J3rASD2F):

```
art
from
role o di nit
“Dand
feverishness
s ran
common lacein
417
ambition,
but
in
```

That's an actual copy and paste from the output of pdftotext and no other application I tried did better.  So I converted everything to .pngs with `pdftoppm -png <input> <output>` (https://imgur.com/a/a5Ofr3D) of the individual pages.  Tesseract will process it, but there are line breaks at the end of each line of the pdf/png.  I want to be able combine all the individual output pages in a way that piper TTS can make an audiofile out of it.  VietOCR seems to format it properly, but I can't get it to process all 600 .pngs and output a single file that can be read by piper.  Bulk processing doesn't fix the line breaks and leaves the pages as separate files.

Single page output from tesseract: https://pastebin.com/HSK19gHk

**Best result so far:** After removing linebreaks with VietOCR: https://pastebin.com/ZqEsFAFc

After removing linebreaks with `sed ':a;N;$!ba;s/\n/\ /g'`: https://pastebin.com/WPY4RHF3

Concatenating the files cat "*txt" > concatfile.txt, but the linebreaks need to be stripped out in some way piper can handle them and so far, all I have found are things that remove them all.

Comment: We can't really help without an example to play with. How can we know which linebreaks should be removed? Oh, and not really relevant, but to concatenate files, all you need is `cat *txt > concatfile.txt`, no need for a loop.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I've added some links.  Is there a place to put the .pdf page?

Comment: The best result is the one from VietOCR which is more or less broken up by paragraph .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you want to remove line breaks *within* paragraphs, but preserve them *between* paragraphs. So perhaps either

```
... | awk -v RS= -v ORS='\n\n' '{$1=$1} 1' | ...
```

or

```
... | perl -00 -lpe '$_ =~ s/\n/ /g' | ...
```

Comment: I tried the perl one and it appears to do what I want.  I've tried to extend this to another book available as an image pdf, but the new one is full-justified and hyphenated text.  Nano was able to find and remove `- `, but perhaps a line to remove the hyphen and linebreak from lines ending with [an incomplete word followed by] a hyphen first followed by the line to remove all the intraparagraph line breaks would solve that problem.
Page image: https://imgur.com/a/PF9ZOet
Tesseract out: https://pastebin.com/Ss574qdN

Comment: perl out: https://pastebin.com/02CAtN7Q
nano out: https://pastebin.com/x5vdxwQS

Answer (score 1):

You can replace newlines with spaces with ([ref](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/sed-remove-m-and-line-feeds-under-unix-linux-bsd-appleosx/)):

```
sed ':a;N;$!ba;s/\n/ /g' txtfile.txt
```

Thus, you could combine all your files and strip out any newline character with:

```
sed ':a;N;$!ba;s/\n/ /g' *txt > outputfile.txt
```

Comment: Does not have the same output as VietOCR, it just removes the linebreaks.

Comment: That was what you asked, so I gave you a command that just removes linebreaks.

Comment: This is a work in progress I'm afraid: AI TTS (that is of decent quality) is relatively new and I've never needed to OCR anything for it before.  I did state that "VietOCR seems to format it properly, but I can't get it to process all 600 .pngs and output a single file that can be read by piper."